# Sending as Unknown number in Hangouts

Tags: sms, mms, google-hangouts

In Hangouts 3.1.89134953 I get a "Sending as Unknown number" message at the top of my texts.  I googled for this message and found nothing.

What does this message mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are not registered for hangouts. Try navigating to hamburger menu -> Settings -> [your email] -> Scroll to Account section, and check to see if your phone number is confirmed.